# How to create generic DataContract Classes for JSON

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, json

Ok so I have been trying to figure out a good way to do this but I am a bit stuck.

I have a SQL database that currently facilitates a website running in asp.net, I have been tasked with removing the website and create a new website, but still keep some functionality from the old database. This has led to the idea of creating an endpoint for the database or the server to output a json that will later be scraped by the new website.

The tutorial for asp.net asks to use DataContract classes to create the Json format, which is fine for pulling from tables. For example:

```
[DataContract]
class People
{
    [DataMember]
    internal string firstName;

    [DataMember]
    internal string lastName;

    [DataMember]
    internal string title;
}
```

this is fine for something simple like `SELECT * FROM PEOPLE` but it gets complicated when I want to do more complicated things like inner joins, varied tables, or if I don't even know what the SQL query will be but i can produce a JSON output based on the SQL query.

My question is, is there a way to generify the creation of the DataContract class based on the query string being fulfilled? Is there a good method for creating a catch all DataContract for JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is strongly typed; so the *qualified* answer is no. If you don't know the data types/names ahead of time you can't create a class for them.

That being said; you can always create a `JObject` from JSON with Newtonsoft.Json; which will basically act as a key-value pair collection (which is, of course, what JSON really is). That's probably your best bet if you can't create the actual classes.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. In a nut shell I would need to figure out what queries before hand in order to create the DataContract. I do know what they are going to be. Or what I can create for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you are using a `MVC` project, I would recommend you read:

[ASP.Net Music Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1)

There, you gonna find a complete tutorial from scratch, with examples and a lot of helpful simplified documentation.

Also, is good approach if you want to learn more, how to use `Linq`.

[Getting Started with LINQ in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq)

For example, I you already have your database `Mapped`, you would do using `DbContext` or simple queries.

`var people = db.People.OrderBy(x => x. firstName);`

But, you asked a very general question, you have to be more specific to try to help you.

Comment: Lol; his question must be really general because I think we answered two completely different ones. Does this have *anything* to do with JSON?

Comment: He didn't add code, then, I don't know if want to do it without knowledge about how to use the technology. Also, the question "The tutorial for asp.net asks to use DataContract classes to create the Json format, which is fine for pulling from tables."., well...   @BradleyDotNET